# Generate all possible combination of numbers, letters, symbols python

Tags: python

I only managed to generate all possible combination of letters in python.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product
minimum_length = 0
maximum_length = 1
for length in range(minimum_length, maximum_length + 1):
    for combo in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=length):
        print(''.join(combo))
```

I only managed to do lowercase

Please help thanks

Comment: So use `ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase`.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks, what about numbers and symbols

Comment: `numbers` and `punctuation`.

Comment: You went as far as importing `ascii_lowercase` and gave up? You didn't think to check for `ascii_uppercase`, or even just a way to turn the lower case letters into uppercase with a function? You didn't check the docs for `ascii_digits`, or `ascii_letters`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) you can leverage the following:

1. string.ascii_lowercase
2. string.ascii_uppercase
3. string.punctuation
4. string.digits

Answer (score 1):

You can import uppercase letters, numbers, and symbols from the same module (or just define a list containing them yourself).

Then combine them into one list and create combinations out of that.

Modifying your code, it would look like this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, punctuation, digits
from itertools import product

minimum_length = 0
maximum_length = 3

ALLOWED_CHARACTERS = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase + punctuation + digits

for length in range(minimum_length, maximum_length + 1):
    for combo in product(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS, repeat=length):
        print(''.join(combo))
```